# Django: how do I structure my app to use many databases

Tags: python, django, database-migration

For specific historic and technical reasons a new SQLite database has to be created for every script run, we might have a hundred such databases per day. Those are all of the same type, all have the same tables. We also have a master PostgreSQL database.

The Django app has to be able to read and write to both types of the database.

How should we structure the app and models so that this is possible:

- Create a new SQLite database and create (migrate) tables inside for every script run.
- If possible, make sure that some models are only saved in SQLite and others only in PostgreSQL.
- When I do a Django migration, only the PostgreSQL models change.

Comment: What does "for every script run" mean?  At any given time, there's one SQLite database, and one PosgtreSQL database?

Comment: Every time the script runs it should create a new SQLite database where the results of the script are saved. There are hundreds of SQLite databases and new are added daily. At any time, a user might decide to inspect any one of these databases, so all have to be available. Imagine customer archive, each customer in it's own database... Only one PostgreSQL DB though.

Answer (score 0):

> Create a new SQLite database and create (migrate) tables inside for every script run.

If you set up your scripts as [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/) then you could achieve this by customising your `manage.py` and `settings.py` files to configure the sqlite database settings from eg env vars or passed in command line args

perhaps you would wrap it all in a bash script, vaguely something like

```
export DB_NAME=this_script_run_id
./manage.py syncdb
./manage.py migrate
./manage.py my_custom_command
```

> If possible, make sure that some models are only saved in SQLite and others only in PostgreSQL.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers

> When I do a Django migration, only the PostgreSQL models change.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#synchronizing-your-databases